# How to enter Carriage Return in XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am programming a simple web app. I have the following xml :`

```
<pelis>
    <nombre id="avengers">Valoracion de Avengers Engame
        <Valoracion>Calificacion general: 7.5</Valoracion>
        <Valorpro>Calificacion de Cartelera Tinajo: 8</Valorpro>
        <ComentariosP>Positivo: Buena pelicula, con un argumento interesante y envolvente. Las escenas estan bien rodadas y las coreografias bien ejecutadas. La banda sonora es buena, asi como el vestuario y sobre todo el maquillaje y los efectos especiales.</ComentariosP>
        <ComentariosN>Negativo: Demasiado larga para nuestro gusto. Algunos fallos de guion y de realizacion. El sonido en algunas escenas es demasiado elevado y poco claro.  El argumento es predecible desde muy temprano.</ComentariosN>

    </nombre>


    <nombre id="mamma">Valoracion de Mamma Mia!
        <Valoracion>Calificacion general: 8</Valoracion> 
        <Valorpro>Calificacion de Cartelera Tinajo: 8</Valorpro>
        <ComentariosP>Positivo: Pelicula muy recomendable. Unifica una comedia elaborada con una trama interesante y adictiva. La banda sonora de ABBA es impecable, sumado a un escenario espectacular, asi como unas coreografias muy elaboradas.</ComentariosP>
        <ComentariosN>Negativo: Guion predecible. En algunas partes se hace un poco aburrida y no consigue captar al espectador. </ComentariosN>

    </nombre>



    <nombre id="hobbit">Valoracion de El Hobbit
        <Valoracion>Calificacion general: 8</Valoracion> 
        <Valorpro>Calificacion de Cartelera Tinajo: 10</Valorpro>
        <ComentariosP>Positivo: Gran película. Al igual que sus predecesoras (El señor de los Anillos I,II y III), es una obra de arte. Música impresionante, universo envolvente, escenas increibles, trama interesante, vestuario peculiar y una infinidad de aspectos positivos.</ComentariosP>
        <ComentariosN>Negativo: El unico punto negativo es que puede ser un poco larga</ComentariosN>

    </nombre>



    <nombre id="hotel">Valoracion de Hotel Transilvania
        <Valoracion>Calificacion general: 8.5</Valoracion> 
        <Valorpro>Calificacion de Cartelera Tinajo: 8</Valorpro>
        <ComentariosP>Positivo: Una comedia para toda la familia. Peculiar en gran medida, dado que enfoca a los monstruos como seres humanizados. Buena trama, actores conocidos. Muy entretenida.</ComentariosP>
        <ComentariosN>Negativo: No tiene ningun punto negativo destacable</ComentariosN>

    </nombre>




    <nombre id="lobo">Valoracion de El Lobo de Wall Street
        <Valoracion>Calificacion general: 8</Valoracion> 
        <Valorpro>Calificacion de Cartelera Tinajo: 9</Valorpro>
        <ComentariosP>Positivo: Una pelicula muy curiosa. Cuenta con grandes actores, un guion elaborado, unas escenas muy bien rodadas. Se sigue con gran interes y tiene giros que la convierten en un peliculon</ComentariosP>
        <ComentariosN>Negativo: Demasiado larga (3 horas de duracion)</ComentariosN>

    </nombre>
</pelis>`
```

and I also have the following XSL to transform it to HTML:[image]

What I want is that all the text that will be shown in the html have carriage return after every line. I have tried adding 
 and also what you can see in the code, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Please post your code **as code**, not as picture.

Answer (score 0):

Because *XSLT* output is *HTML*, you can use `<br/>` for that. Or CSS for the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

A NL or CR character in an HTML document displays as an ordinary space in the browser. If you want text to start on a new line when rendered in the browser, you typically want to output a `<br>` element.

Comment: So, you recommend to put <br> in the xsl after the statement, like this:  <Valoracion>Calificacion general: 8</Valoracion> <br> ?

Comment: XSLT is XML, not HTML, so it needs to be written as `<br/>`.

Comment: Actually, I'm really confused by what you are trying to do. You're outputting the text in HTML paragraphs, so it will be rendered with new lines automatically; you don't need to do anything special. Unless you want newlines in the actual lexical HTML, in which case use indent="yes".

Comment: What I want is that when I execute the html generated using the xml and the xsl files the CR stay the same, so if I have put a CR in the xml so the next sentence start in the consecutive line, that could be shown on the browser, but I dont know how.